# Converting a currency field to a monthly or yearly amount

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm creating an expense form which asked for costs but in either monthly or yearly amounts. I was thinking I would first create a currency field to ask for the amount. Then add a Choice Box with two options "Monthly" or "Yearly" to designate what that amount is.  I will have a list of these expenses such as utilities, insurance, etc.

So at the end of the form, I want to be able to calculate their total expenses. But how do I calculate if an amount is a monthly or yearly value?  If it's monthly, then multiply by 12, or yearly, divide by 12.  That way I can provide total expenses in monthly and yearly numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Assume you have a Currency field called `Utilities` and a Choice field called `Timeframe`, with the options `Monthly` and `Yearly`.  Your calculations would then be:

Monthly Amount

```
=Utilities / (Timeframe = "Monthly" ? 1 : 12)
```

Yearly Amount

```
=Utilities * (Timeframe = "Yearly" ? 1 : 12)
```

And of course you can just keep adding on additional items to the calculation for each type of cost.

Comment: Hi Jamie, thanks for the response. This is great, but the calculations are still not quite right which I can look into. But let me ask what does the "1 : 12" do? I'm trying to understand the syntax. Thank you!

Comment: @TimC. this syntax has been a challenge for many of our users, so we may introduce another way to handle conditional statements, like If(condition, true result, false result).  The ? : syntax is called a ternary operator and is used to return one of two values based on conditional logic.  The syntax is <condition> ? <true result> : <false result).  This comes from the C language and therefore also exists in JavaScript as well so it is very familiar to web developers.  However, like I said, it is cryptic so we may provide an alternative syntax.

Comment: Hi Jamie, thank you again, this helps out a lot! I was able to get the form to work.  If I may ask a followup question? I split up some of the questions to multiple pages to keep the form looking clean. How to I reference variables on different pages?  In other words, have a page for Housing budget and a page for Auto budget.  But I want to now have a total, how to I add these pages together?  Thanks!